# Devise: Using registerable and omniauthable in the same app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

How can I use both `registerable` and `omniauthable` modules in Devise?

Specifically I'd like to be able to let users do the following:

1. Register/login with email and password
2. Register/login with Facebook (via omniauth)
3. Attach or remove a Facebook account to their account so they can login with either their email or their Facebook account.

I don't know how to do 3 at all.

1 and 2 are done, but where it gets weird is if the user registered with a Facebook account, I don't need to show (or require) them to enter a password to update their profile.

So, how can I...

1. Let users attach a Facebook account to their current account so they can login with either.
2. If the user only signed up with a Facebook account, how do I hide (and not require) the password fields when editing their settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let users attach a Facebook account to their current account so
>   they can login with either.

- in the user setting page add a link to  "link to Facebook account"
- the link just drive the user through the normal Facebook authentication processes using the OmniauthCallbacksController, just make sure in your OmniauthCallbacksController facebook method you add some code to see if the user is already logged in and if he is you just add an authentication token for the user (I have a table that stores the authentication token for each user)

> If the user only signed up with a Facebook account, how do I hide
>   (and not require) the password fields when editing their settings.

Take a look at this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this article interesting:

http://www.ruby-on-rails-outsourcing.com/2011/05/06/how-to-merge-facebook-account-into-existing-user-account-using-devise/

Just ran through this myself as I was looking into the same thing, and it worked great for me, but one additional note that is incredibly easy to overlook as it's barely mentioned in a single paragraph; don't forget to generate a migration to add facebook_uid to the user model.